# Why can I not pass a more general object in an out parameter?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

**Why** the c# compiler are not capable to accept:

```
string propValue = "2017/12/01";
object propObjValue = null;
DateTime.TryParse(propValue, out propObjValue);
```

**Compiler error:** Argument 2: cannot convert from 'out object' to 'out System.DateTime'

However it do accept:

```
string propValue = "2017/12/01";
object propObjValue = null;
propObjValue = DateTime.Parse(propValue);
```

Which is equivalent, except in the second approach I need to do try/catch to avoid parsing issues.

Comment: `DateTime` is an `object`, but an `object` is not a `DateTime`.

Comment: You're calling two completely different methods. There's no requirement that different methods "act similarly" just because of similar names

Comment: If you read the [`DateTime` info on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.DateTime);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7), you'd understand. The inheritance hierarchy is `Object -> ValueType -> DateTime`.

Comment: Shame it closed. I was writing an answer about how `out` is a lie and only `ref` really exists, and so how you have to accept that the called method can call specific methods on the passed in variable, after avoiding `null`s. I'm not sure I see that in the linked Q

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The linked question specifically covers the variable being modified from outside the scope of the method as the reason that this doesn't work, so that's already there.

Comment: Yes, I just realized is already covered by the referenced question, the problem is that "out" can modify the object parameter inside the function, not only assigning a value. So if I pass a more general object they are not allowed to modify DateTime.